# Slider control buttons are not working properly

Tags: javascript, function, button, slider

```js
let images=["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519389950473-47ba0277781c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487017159836-4e23ece2e4cf?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497215842964-222b430dc094?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462826303086-329426d1aef5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"];

let i=0;

window.onload = function() {
    autoSlider();    
};

function autoSlider(){
    console.log("Main function");
    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];

    if(i<images.length-1){
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }

  
}
let interval=setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);


function rightSlide(){

    clearInterval(interval); 
    console.log("Right function");
    if(i<images.length-1){
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }
    
    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];
 

    setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);


}   

function leftSlide(){
    console.log("Left function");
    clearInterval(interval);
   

    if(i>0){
        i=i-1;
    }else{
        i=images.length-1;
    }

    setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);

    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];
}
```

```css
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css");
.slider{
    position: relative;
}

.slider img{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.slider div{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 22.5rem;
    /* background-color: black; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,black, transparent);
    opacity: 60%;
    padding-left: 1rem;

}

#slider_sub{
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg,black, transparent);
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.fas{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mahindra Online Showroom</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<body>
   
 
    <section class="slider">

        <img  alt="Slider_Image">

        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" onclick="leftSlide()"></i>
        </div>

        <div id="slider_sub">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" onclick="rightSlide()"></i>
        </div>
        
    </section>

   

</body>
</html>
```

I created an automatic slider but when I am trying to add right and left buttons to it, It is showing some unnatural behaviours like Missing the image order (sliding randomly), Sliding as fast as I click on the button and not sliding till I double click(left button) on it.

Please let me know where it went wrong.

```
<section class="slider">

        <img  alt="Slider_Image">

        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left" onclick="leftSlide()"></i>
        </div>

        <div id="slider_sub">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" onclick="rightSlide()"></i>
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

--JavaScript--

```
let images=["images/a.jpg","images/b.jpg","images/c.jpg","images/d.jpg"];

let i=0;

window.onload = function() {
    autoSlider();    
};

function autoSlider(){
    console.log("Main function");
    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];

    if(i<images.length-1){
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }

  
}
let interval=setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);


function rightSlide(){

    clearInterval(interval); 
    console.log("Right function");
    if(i<images.length-1){
        i++;
    }else{
        i=0;
    }
    
    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];
 

    setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);


}   

function leftSlide(){
    console.log("Left function");
    clearInterval(interval);
   

    if(i>0){
        i=i-1;
    }else{
        i=images.length-1;
    }

    setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);

    document.querySelector(".slider img").src=images[i];
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the content `i` in the init function?! Looks like the if/else in the main function should be removed. Also, maybe post a runable code snippet. Would be easier to help then

Comment: Sorry to ask, I am new to this platform. How to post runable code snippet? Do you mean to include total code in the post?

Comment: There is a button for it in your wyswig editor toolbar in between the`image` and `list` icons that shows `<>`. You can add html/css/js to a single snippet which allows executing the code right here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: You should for sure change the `setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);` in your left/right functions to `interval = setInterval(autoSlider, 4000);` as you are clearing `clearInterval(interval)` in the autoSlide function. You create a new, unclearable interval on every click at the moment

Comment: Only one problem was resolved (Sliding as fast as I click on the button). Rest of the two are still there.